# Is there a way on Atlas to put a Margin around feature but also use Predefined scales?

Tags: qgis, scale, atlas

In QGIS, how can I put a margin around a feature but also use predefined scales in Atlas? Like an in-between of the two options. I have a feature that fits in the map but as you can see in the image it almost reach the edges leaving some annotation out of the viewmap, so I would like QGIS to use a smaller scale to better accommodate the drawing.

[image]

I need it to be the same coverage layer with the features - not another layer with a buffer - due to the fact that I have a symbology that depends on it, like the expression that I use to show only the features that touch the atlas feature in more than two vertices.

Tried to create a buffer with "Geometry Generator" around the feature thinking the program would understand that I also want it to appear and so shrink the drawing, but it didn't work. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option you could do, would be to add a few pre-defined scales to your atlas and change them dynamically based on the size of your atlas feature. So if you go to your scale and insert an expression:
[image]

Something along these lines:

```
CASE 
WHEN
area( @atlas_geometry ) <5
THEN 50000
WHEN 
area( @atlas_geometry ) <10
THEN 80000
ELSE 100000
END
```

This will read the size of your feature area and adjust the scale based on that. Of course you will have to change those limits according to your own data. You could also add more scales or use a line length or something else as the geometrical feature to define the scales. If the objects are very irregular, you could wrap the @atlas_geometry inside oriented_bbox, bounds_height or bounds_width functions if those can better classify your data.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem, since I have a pretty amount of parcels that are quite irregular, as much that parcels with 350m² can be very stretch out and only be visible in a 1:500 scale while parcels with 650m² can fit in a 1:350 scale. So there isn't really a pattern to follow, that's why I as looking for a tool that acts just as the "Margin around feature" that comprehends the geometry and chooses the appropriate scale. But thanks for the help!!

Comment: I see. How about if you try and tackle the problem of irregular polygons by replacing the geometries with their bounding boxes. So something like this:
CASE 
WHEN
area( 
oriented_bbox( @atlas_geometry) ) <5
THEN 5000
WHEN 
area( 
oriented_bbox( @atlas_geometry) ) <10
THEN 8000
ELSE 10000
END

Comment: Sorry to wait so long for a feedback, I wasn't having the time to work in this project. Anyway, the oriented_bbox area didn't worked for me, but the bounds_height and bounds_width solved all my problems, and I wouldn't have known theses features existed if it wasn't for your help. Thank you so much truly!!!

Comment: @FelippeM. could you explain how you manage it with bounds_height and bounds_width? I have a similar problem. Tnks!

Comment: Sure! Well, first I created two fields with bounds_height and bounds_width in my layer and then with both values I used the steps described by tjukanov to create a series of conditions with "CASE WHEN" in the scale propertie, for example -> CASE WHEN  bounds_height ( @atlas_geometry)  < 25 AND bounds_width (@atlas_geometry) < 60
THEN 350 END. In the end I had a pretty long expression since I had to go through all the possibilities of my data, but it solved my problem.